# aws-sdk-js seems to be non functional when ran inside of jasmine

Tags: aws-sdk-js

This code is completely non-functional when I put it in a jasmine spec file.  It doesn't matter if it's in side an 'it' block or outside of the test blocks completely, it just stops functioning.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const cf = new AWS.CloudFormation({ apiVersion: "2010-05-15" });
cf.listStacks({}, (err, data) => console.log('cf.listStacks: ', err, data));
```

What could this be?

Answer (score 0):

To test aws-sdk, instead of using the sdk directly, I think you should look at [aws-sdk-mock](https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock).

By using stubs, you can prevent the actual AWS services to be called while testing functions that use the AWS SDK.

Comment: I was considering that very library, but my concern is whether that library actually mocks properly or not.  i.e. am I going to have tests passing that don't pass for real?  Is that an AWS supported tool?

Comment: You should put that sorts of tests as your part of integration tests - to call the actual aws services and build it into your pipeline against the deployed resources. It is not quite appropriate to test these in the unit test layer.

Comment: That's the purpose, is to run it as an integration test.  Is jasmine *only* used for unit tests? I'm not writing any significant amount of code to be worthy of unit testing.  Just a simple layer to coordinate sending/receiving of SQS messages.

Comment: This might be helpful https://www.alxolr.com/articles/how-to-test-locally-aws-sqs-queues-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that because aws-sdk js uses jasmine, they've made it not work from within jasmine.

Besides, it's far better to separate the specific aws code out into a function, and that then calls a "processor" function that handles the incoming or outgoing data.  That way I can test the functionality of the code I wrote, and just trust aws data.  It's much simpler than creating an AWS mock as well.  Plus, it's typically considered bad practise to "mock what you don't own", because you cannot guarantee how it works.